# Game development: OpenGlContext error issue

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am developing game in Android and got `OpenGlContext error`,any suggestions to overcome the same?
Below is my Code:

```
public class GLView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
private OpenGLContext ctx;
private Tunnel3D tunnel;
private boolean created;
private GL10 gl;
private int w;
private int h;
private Bitmap bmp;
private int tex;


public GLView (Context context)
{
// Parent...
super (context);
getHolder ().addCallback (this);

// Internal members..
ctx = new OpenGLContext (OpenGLContext.DEPTH_BUFFER);
gl = (GL10)ctx.getGL ();
tunnel = new Tunnel3D (10, 20);
created = false;

// Enabling the state...
gl.glEnable (GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
gl.glEnable (GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
gl.glEnableClientState (GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glEnableClientState (GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
gl.glEnableClientState (GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

// Loading texture...
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource (context.getResources(), R.drawable.plants03);
tex = loadTexture (gl, bmp);
}

public boolean surfaceCreated (SurfaceHolder holder)
{
synchronized (this)
{
created = true;
}
return true;
}

public void surfaceDestroyed (SurfaceHolder holder)
{
synchronized (this)
{
created = false;
}
}

public void surfaceChanged (SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h)
{
synchronized (this)
{
this.w = w;
this.h = h;
}
}

public void render ()
{
// Check the created flag...
boolean c = false;
synchronized (this)
{
c = created;
}
if (!c) return;

// Start the surface holder...
SurfaceHolder sh = getHolder ();
Canvas g = sh.lockCanvas ();

// Hooking GL with the view...
ctx.makeCurrent (g, null);

// Setting up the projection...
float ratio = (float)w / h;
gl.glMatrixMode (GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity ();
gl.glViewport (0, 0, w, h);
GLU.gluPerspective (gl, 45.0f, ((float)w)/h, 1f, 100f);

// Setting up the modelview...
gl.glMatrixMode (GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glLoadIdentity ();

// Clear the z-buffer...
gl.glClear (GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Render the tunnel...
tunnel.render (gl, -1.6f);
tunnel.nextFrame ();

// OpenGL finish
gl.glFlush ();
gl.glFinish ();

// Finish with hook
ctx.waitGL ();

// End the surface holder...
sh.unlockCanvasAndPost (g);
}

private int loadTexture (GL10 gl, Bitmap bmp)
{
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bmp.height()*bmp.width()*4);
bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
IntBuffer ib = bb.asIntBuffer();

for (int y=0;y<bmp.height();y++)
for (int x=0;x<bmp.width();x++) {
ib.put(bmp.getPixel(x,y));
}
ib.position(0);
bb.position(0);

int[] tmp_tex = new int[1];

gl.glGenTextures(1, tmp_tex, 0);
int tex = tmp_tex[0];
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, bmp.width(), bmp.height(), 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

return tex;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Android's [`GLSurfaceView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html) instead of making your own wrapper. However, if you really want to make your own GL wrapper you should make a correct implementation, which you can find [here](http://code.google.com/p/replicaisland/source/browse/trunk/src/com/replica/replicaisland/GLSurfaceView.java).