# OpenGLContext not found in android extends SurfaceView class

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am creating game.

I am just beginner in game I have some demos.

But i just face the problem when I want to object of   `OpenGLContext`.

Here is my code:

```
public class GLView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
    {
    private OpenGLContext ctx;
    private Tunnel3D      tunnel;
```

at OpenGLContext I got the error.

what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OpenGLContext` is outdated. You should do what I wrote in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592555/game-development-openglcontext-error-issue/6592678#6592678).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592555/game-development-openglcontext-error-issue/6592678#6592678